# How can I fix White Screen passing function on React App?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app based off of a bootcamp project. I'm working on a component that requires the rendering of each of another component using .map(). Once I add that the screen goes to white and no one knows how to fix it.

Component pre-white screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track';
import './TrackList.css'

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {/* <!-- You will add a map method that renders a set of Track components  --> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Code post-white screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track';
import './TrackList.css'

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
                {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track track={track} key={track.id} />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? If so, do you mind posting?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameters inside the `map` function like this:

`{props.tracks.map((track) => <Track key={track.id} />)}`

You can't pass `track={track}` until there's a track property inside the returned promise from your API.